# SqlDataReader: Read varbinary into byte array

Tags: c#, sqldatareader, varbinary, varbinarymax

I have a SQL Server table with a `varbinary(max)` column. I use it to store images in it. The images are selected with an `OpenFileDialog`, translated into a `byte[]` like this

```
public byte[] ConvertImageToByteArray(String filepath)
{
    try
    {
        return File.ReadAllBytes(filepath);
    }
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        throw; 
    }
}
```

and then stored into the database using this line of code:

```
sqlCmd.Parameters.Add("@image", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = image;
```

It looks like this stored in the database, so I guess all seems to work like expected.

[image]

Unfortunately I am unable to load the images back from the datatable.

I am using a `SqlDataReader` to do so:

```
DbSql db = new DbSql();

SqlDataReader dr = db.GetDataReader(sqlCmd);

if (dr.Read())
{
    if (!dr.IsDBNull(1))
        productName = dr.GetString(1);

    if (!dr.IsDBNull(2))
        identNumber = dr.GetString(2);

    [...]

    if (!dr.IsDBNull(23))
        comment = dr.GetString(23);

    if (!dr.IsDBNull(24))
    {
        byte[] image = dr.GetSqlBytes(24).Value;  // <- This is where I try to grab the image
    }
}
```

It seems like I am not able to create a proper `byte[]` with

```
image = dr.GetSqlBytes(24).Value;
```

because my next step is not able to turn it into an image again:

```
public Image ConvertImageFromByteArray(byte[] array)
{
        try
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(array);
            return Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
        catch (Exception) { throw; }
    }
```

**EDIT:**
When trying something like
    `pictureBox.Image = ConvertImageFromByteArray(image)`
I get an error saying "Invalid parameter" (self translated, saying "Ungültiger Parameter" in german)
[image]

Anyone able to offer a solution?

Comment: try `image = (byte[])dr[24];`

Comment: Why are you read data using GetString which will corrupt the data.  dr.Read() reads one row of the database which contains the entire binary object.  So just use : MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream((byte[])dr.GetValue(23));  which will read the contents of the 24th column.

Comment: @Nkosi `image` is a `byte[]`. Just added that to my question and also the error message I get.

Comment: Can you copy the complete error. I am certain it provided more details than that

Comment: @Nkosi Sorry! Absolutely forgot to upload the picture -.-

Comment: Zohar Peled has it right...

Comment: @ChrisCatignani Unfortunately @zohar-peled's solution is not working. It throws exactly the same error as `image = dr.GetSqlBytes(24).Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you cast your varbinary(MAX) to a byte array

```
image = (byte[])dr[24];
```

Try this..

```
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(image);
    imagePictureBox.Image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
```

This is how I create the byte array...

```
    if (File.Exists(sLogoName) == false)
       throw new Exception("File Not Found: " + sLogoName);
    FileStream sourceStream = new FileStream(sLogoName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
    int streamLength = (int)sourceStream.Length;
    Byte[] byLogo = new Byte[streamLength];
    sourceStream.Read(byLogo, 0, streamLength);
    sourceStream.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The problem was not how I tried to load the image from the database but how I stored it.
Using the code you provided to write the byte array I am now able to load the image. Awesome :)

Comment: Glad that worked...I had problems with it originally.